# Как вернуть результаты цикла for

Tags: python, циклы, for

Как вернуть все значения списка? `return` прерывает цикл после первой итерации а как сделать так что бы цикл вытаскивал все элементы `def`.

```
data = res.json()
temp_conditionfff = data['list']

for item in list(temp_conditionfff):
    testitemmin = item['main']['temp']
    testitemmin = str (testitemmin)
    testitemax = item['weather'][0]['description']
    testitemax = str(testitemax)
    item = 'Погода на три часа:' + testitemmin + ': ' + testitemax
    return item

print(weath())`
```

Answer (score 2):

`yield` — это ключевое слово которое используется так же, как и слово `return`. Разница в том, что функция при этом начинает возвращать генератор вместо значения.

```
t = "12345"

def f():
    for i in t:
        yield i


list(f())
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

Answer (score 1):

## yield

Если в качестве итерируемого объекта используется функция, то она будет вызываться с каждой итерацией, но код, находящийся перед циклом, который содержит `yield`, будет выполнен только 1 раз

```
def main():
    print('Function call')
    for i in range(3):
        print('func: ', i)
        yield

print('Start')
for x in main():
    print('iter: ', x)

Start
Function call
func:  0
iter:  0
func:  1
iter:  1
func:  2
iter:  2
```

---

Если `yield` возвращает элемент итерируемого объекта, тогда можно использовать конструкцию `yield from`

Данный код

```
for i in range(10):
    yield i
```

аналогичен этому

```
yield from range(10)
```

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас есть некий список, каждый элемент которого вы хотите подать на вход функции, а потом сохранить результат в  аналогичный список, но уже с ответами можно так:

```
result = [my_func(x) for x in my_list]
```

Или

```
result = map(my_func, my_list)
```

Можете использовать простую запись цикла и `append`:

```
result = []
for i in my_list:
    result.append(my_func(i))
```

Также вы можете сохранить входные данные с результатами в словарь:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3]
def f(x): return x**2
result = {s: f(s) for s in my_list}
# {1: 1, 2: 4, 3: 9}
```